# Convert " (GMT-04:00) Eastern Daylight Time (America/New_York) " to "EDT"

Tags: javascript, salesforce

How would you collect the first letter of each word in a string and avoid (GMT-04:00) and (America/New_York) details?

```
 TimeZone tz = Userinfo.getTimeZone();        
   String timeZone = String.valueOf(tz.getDisplayName());    

   Result:: "(GMT-04:00) Eastern Daylight Time (America/New_York)" 
   Display like : "EDT"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem:
Using regular experssion we can filter out unnecessary data. Then we will user the string and split with using a space. Then we can fetch first character of each string to form EDT.

```
const str = "(GMT-04:00) Eastern Daylight Time (America/New_York)";
const updatedStr = str.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "");
const results = updatedStr.split(" ").map(item => item.charAt(0)).join("");
console.log(results);
```